# Match values of multiple columns by using 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

**Sample DF:**

```
ID   Name     Match1    Random_Col    Match2    Price    Match3     Match4       Match5
1    Apple      Yes     Random Value   No        10      Yes        Yes          Yes
2    Apple      Yes     Random Value1  No        10      Yes        Yes          No
3    Apple      Yes     Random Value2  No        15      No         Yes          Yes
4    Orange     No      Random Value   Yes       12      Yes        Yes          No
5    Orange     No      Random Value   Yes       12      No         No           No
6    Banana     Yes     Random Value   No        15      Yes        No           No
7    Apple      Yes     Random Value   No        15      No        Yes          Yes
```

**Expected DF:**

```
ID   Name     Match1    Random_Col    Match2  Price Match3  Match4 Match5 Final_Match
1    Apple      Yes     Random Value   No      10    Yes    Yes    Yes   Full
2    Apple      Yes     Random Value1  No      10    Yes    Yes    No  Partial
3    Apple      Yes     Random Value2  No      15    No     Yes    Yes Partial
4    Orange     No      Random Value   Yes     12    Yes    Yes    No    Full
5    Orange     No      Random Value   Yes     12    No     No     No Partial
6    Banana     Yes     Random Value   No      15    Yes    No     No   Full
7    Apple      Yes     Random Value   No      15    No     Yes    Yes Partial
```

**Problem Statement:**

1. If combination `Name` and `Price` is non-repetitive simply put `Full` in `Final_Match` column (Example ID 6)
2. If the combination `Name` and `Price` are repetitive then within them count `Yes` in Match1 to Match5 columns, whichever has greater "Yes" put `Full` for that one and `Partial` for the other (Example ID 1 & 2 and 4,5)
3. If the combination `Name` and `Price` are repetitive then within an ID count `Yes` in Match1 to Match5 columns,if they have equal "Yes" put `Partial` in both (Example ID 3,7)

**Code**

```
s = (df.replace({'Yes': 1, 'No': 0})
     .iloc[:, 1:]
     .sum(1))

df['final_match'] = np.where(s.groupby(df[['Price','Name']]).rank(ascending=False).eq(1), 'Full ','Partial')
```

The above code works when I had to `groupby` by only 1 column lets say `Name` but it is not working for combination.

Any help!!

Comment: Can you also provide code to reproduce your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#count Yes values only in Match columns
s = df.filter(like='Match').eq('Yes').sum(axis=1)
#mask for unique combinations
m1 = ~df.duplicated(['Price','Name'], keep=False)
#create new column filled by Series s
m2 = df.assign(new=s).groupby(['Price','Name'])['new'].rank(ascending=False).eq(1)
#chain masks by bitwise OR
df['final_match'] = np.where(m1 | m2, 'Full ','Partial')
print (df)

   ID    Name Match1     Random_Col Match2  Price Match3 Match4 Match5  \
0   1   Apple    Yes   Random Value     No     10    Yes    Yes    Yes   
1   2   Apple    Yes  Random Value1     No     10    Yes    Yes     No   
2   3   Apple    Yes  Random Value2     No     15     No    Yes    Yes   
3   4  Orange     No   Random Value    Yes     12    Yes    Yes     No   
4   5  Orange     No   Random Value    Yes     12     No     No     No   
5   6  Banana    Yes   Random Value     No     15    Yes     No     No   
6   7   Apple    Yes   Random Value     No     15     No    Yes    Yes   

  final_match  
0       Full   
1     Partial  
2     Partial  
3       Full   
4     Partial  
5       Full   
6     Partial
```